# Get deadlock when try to received value twice

Tags: multithreading, go

I watch the awesome video about [Advanced Go Concurrency Patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDDwwePbDtw). At the beginning Sameer Ajmani shows a ping pong application.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Ball struct{ hits int }

func main() {
    table := make(chan *Ball)
    go player("ping", table)
    go player("pong", table)

    table <- new(Ball) // game on; toss the ball
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(<-table) // game over; grab the ball
}

func player(name string, table chan *Ball) {
    for {
        ball := <-table
        ball.hits++
        fmt.Println(name, ball.hits)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        table <- ball
    }
}
```

The code how it works, I understand to 90 percent. They are two goroutines they send to each other messages, ping and pong, during the main thread sleeps.

Then I try following

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Ball struct{ hits int }

func main() {
    table := make(chan *Ball)
    go player("ping", table)
    go player("pong", table)

    table <- new(Ball) // game on; toss the ball
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(<-table) // game over; grab the ball
    fmt.Println(<-table) // game over; grab the ball
}

func player(name string, table chan *Ball) {
    for {
        ball := <-table
        ball.hits++
        fmt.Println(name, ball.hits)
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        table <- ball
    }
}
```

I've got here a deadlock and really do not understand why. Look at the last line in the go routine, I try to receive value from channel like the second last line. In background the two goroutines still continue loop and send to each other value. It seems to be for me a multiple receiver for table variable channel.

My main question is, what I've got by the second sample a deadlock?

Comment: Do not grab ball. Just close channel. To check that channel already closed, use x, ok := <-c notation. Example http://play.golang.org/p/N579duQZOg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In background the two goroutines still continue loop and send to each other value.

**No, they don't.**

When you make the channel with `make(chan *Ball)`, you are making an unbuffered channel. This is equivalent to saying `make(chan *Ball,0)`, which means that the channel can fit 0 things in it - or, more explicitly, any writes to the channel will block until another routine reads from the channel, and vice versa.

The order of execution with an unbuffered channel is this:

- Player "ping" created, tries to read from table with  `ball := <-table`, blocked until `table` is written to
- Player "pong" created, tries to read from table  with `ball := <-table`, blocked until `table` is written to
- Main writes the Ball to `table` with the following line:

  ```
   table <- new(Ball) // game on; toss the ball
  ```

  This is not blocked because someone is waiting to read on the channel.
- Now ping reads the ball (execution continues after ping's `ball := <-table`)
- Ping puts the ball on the table with `table <- ball`, not blocked because pong is waiting
- Pong reads the ball (execution continues after pong's `ball := <-table`)
- Pong puts the ball on the table with `table <- ball`, not blocked because ping is waiting
- Ping reads the ball (execution continues after ping's `ball := <-table`)
- ....etc

  - Until main ends the game by reading the ball instead of one of the players

This is a great example of using a channel to ensure that only one routine is running at once.

To end the game, the main thread simply snatches the ball out of the channel after one second:

```
 time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
 fmt.Println(<-table) // game over; grab the ball
```

After this, the `table` channel will be empty, and any further reads on it will block.

- At this point, both `player` routines are blocked at `ball := <- table`.

If you do a further `<-table` read in the main thread, *that* read will also block, until a routine tries to write to the table channel. However, since no other routines are running, you have a deadlock (all goroutines are blocked).

---

**Ok. Can I just put two balls in the channel then?**

No.

If we try to put two balls in the channel, we'll probably get the output:

```
Ping 1
Pong 1
```

because both `player` routines will be stuck trying to put their ball back into the channel - but nobody will be trying to read it. The order looks like this:

- Player "ping" created, tries to read from table, blocked
- Player "pong" created, tries to read from table, blocked
- main puts the first ball into `table` (not blocked because someone is waiting to read)
- main puts the second ball into `table` (not blocked because someone is waiting to read)
- Ping reads the first ball
- Pong reads the second ball
- Ping puts the first ball on the table, blocked because nobody is waiting to read
- Pong puts the second ball on the table, blocked because nobody is waiting to read
- Both players are blocked

  - Until main ends the game by reading both balls.

[Here's a program to illustrate](http://play.golang.org/p/mm3lG25TZx)

As a commenter points out, a better thing to do to end the game would be to close the channel. But, I hope this discussion has cleared up your confusion.

Comment: When I delete `the line table <- new(Ball) // game on; toss the ball` why then I've got a deadlock?

Comment: Again, you'll have a deadlock because all goroutines are waiting on reading the channel (but nobody is going to write to the channel). I've edited my answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Main thread steal the ball from other goroutine, because it is ready to receive the ball and other goroutine is still busy to receive the ball right? One send an another receive. In the program, their are two potential receiver, right?

Comment: Once `main`'s sleep is over and the send in `player` is hit, there are two possible receivers (`main`, and the other `player`). I don't think Go defines an order for waiting receivers to execute - so it's possible that the other `player` could receive the ball instead of `main`, but once `main` grabs it, no further execution is possible in the `player` routines.

Comment: You are golang expert. Thanks a lot for help. To read about channel it is easy to understand, but to practice it, so difficult.